# Make command not producing an executable file

Tags: c++, cmake

I just started using C++ and want to use CMake to compile a simple hello world program, but I don't know what to do with the MakeFile once it is produced. I have a directory called tutorial that contains my tutorial.cpp file containing the hello world code. I also have a CMakeLists file that contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14.4)
project (tutorial)
add_executable(tutorial tutorial.cpp)
```

When I run the command `cmake .` from the tutorial directory in my terminal, all the correct (at least I think they are correct) files are produced and I get the following output:

```
-- The C compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- The CXX compiler identification is AppleClang 10.0.1.10010046
-- Check for working C compiler:             
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler:     
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to:     
/Users/kshitijsachan/Documents/cs/cpp/tutorial
```

I then typed in `make` in the terminal and got no output. How can I actually run the makefile that was produced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `make <some_valid_target_name>` - like `make all` or `make install` (if such commonly used targets exist) or whatever other targets your project defined. Check your projects documentation or CMakeLists.txt file for valid target names.

See also [cmake_add_executable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) which adds a target.

Comment: 'tutorial' is just the name of the executable that will be created

Comment: Running `make all` also does nothing. After typing in `make tutorial`, I get the error message: "make: *** No rule to make target `tutorial'.  Stop." 

What's going on and how can I fix this?

Comment: Ah I just realized there was actually a problem with my original tutorial.cpp file, thanks!